# multiple particle effect at a time in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, effect, particles

I am working on a project in libgdx and i am stuck at a point I want  an algorithm or Java code so that I can create multiple explosion whenever I click on screen irrespective to  the one which is already running , if I click on screen 10 times at a time I can see 10 explosions.
Please help me to do this?

Comment: You should post your relevant existing code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution:

Keep an `Array<>` of running explosions. On render, iterate through them - for each one that is not finsihed, draw. Then, loop through and remove the finished ones and release back to the pool (if you are using pooling, which you really should), or dispose. You could combine these steps by using a [DelayedRemovalArray](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/DelayedRemovalArray.java)<> and use `begin()` before starting the loop and `end()` after.

On click, add a new effect to the array.

I used this method to create an "area effect" explosion where lots of explosion effects are spawned over a set time.